# Does namespace pollution in Java or C# exist (like in C++)?

Tags: java, c#, c++, namespaces

I've been puzzled by the concept of how Java and C# handles namespaces.

**Firstly**, examples of namespace pollution in some programming languages:

1. `using namespace std` for C++.

   Everyone in the industry frowns upon it, but beginners are still taught to do that when starting programming. [Here's a SO question about the advice for handling global namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267908/polluting-the-global-namespace)
2. `import math.*` in Python

When taking a Python class I was told that doing that is not recommended as it pollutes the namespace and firstly allows for access to all methods in the math library without `Math.functionname` but might cause collisions when writing a method with a duplicate name. It also apparently causes more work for the interpreter since it imports all of the functions, even those that aren't used.

3. open module in Ocaml
   Doing this on the toplevel or in ML files [Might cause conflicts](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/modules.html) in naming as well. Especially if writing a library.
4. [JavaScript namespace pollution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted)

**The Question:**

Does "namespace pollution" (i.e importing a ton of methods that will potentially cause conflict when writing methods) exist in C# and Java (they are similar in many ways)? Why not?

*And of course the related questions that are too similar to ask another question:*

-Is it because perhaps we have to explicitly `@Override` things or there's some kind of preventive measure?

-Or it exists, but it's not a thing because it doesn't cause as much havoc as 'using namespace std', and that I'm not aware of it being relatively new to software development out of academic classes?

**Example**

I find myself `using` a lot of libraries in C# to avoid having to retype the namespaces for a variable, like `XElement`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//the ones above are auto-generated by Visual Studio, too

using System.Xml.Linq;
```

will avoid me having to do `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` every single time I create an XElement. Much like how we always have to do `std::cout` in C++

or in Java where I commonly see: `import java.util.linkedlist`, even `import java.util.*`

**Won't these cause namespace pollution** if my class is used elsewhere? Or is it because they will only be "polluting" that particular class scope and not in other classes that might import or inherit my class?

I tried searching for an answer but couldn't find one for this, I might be phrasing the search wrongly though.

**EDIT 4/20/2015**:

As mentioned by @RealSkeptic, it turns out that Java wildcard imports are also discouraged. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad)

In addition to the accepted answer and answers below, imports in Java and C# are contained within themselves, so even if someone uses a wildcard kind of import that adds unused method names to the namespace, it does not affect the other classes. On a class level, if a collision in names does occur, Java and C# compilers will throw an error citing ambiguous imports and fail to further compile until the issue is resolved (by renaming functions for example).

Comment: "Won't these cause namespace pollution if my class is used elsewhere?" It's not entirely clear what you mean by this, but a using directive in one source file has no effect on what is imported in other source files.

Comment: Similar recommendations exist in Java: Avoid using `import something.*` and don't use the default package (i.e. always have a `package` statement in your classes). The reasons are similar.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, I meant if I wrote a class/library, shared it, and someone else imports it to use, does it cause pollution like in the case of C++ using namespace std. (not sure if I worded it properly, apologies).

Comment: @matrixanomaly: Unfortunately knowing the details of what's going on in C++, it's hard to say - but imports and using directives don't "pollute" anything in C# or Java.

Comment: "Ambiguous references" would be an issue if you're trying to use a class whose name exists in two namespaces you are `using` in the same file (when compiling)... If that's what you mean. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141043/resolving-an-ambiguous-reference

Comment: @RealSkeptic that's a good point now that I explicitly Google it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad

Comment: Are you making up a problem, which does not exist (programming without namespaces worked well 1 or some years ago)?

Comment: @DieterLücking As per the question asks, I am unsure if it exists in Java/C#, where I am trying to understand the differences between programming languages and felt this is something I couldn't find and come to my own conclusion to, so I don't think of that as making up a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already pointed out by others, the problem of namespace pollution is not as prominent in Java as it is in C++. The main reason why namespace pollution is a problem in C++ (and thus called "pollution" in the first place) is that it may cause errors in other modules. This is explained in more detail in [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

(The concerning thing here is that this may not only refer to *compile* errors: For compile errors, you are *forced* to do something and to resolve ambiguities. The really concerning thing is that it may cause the code to still compile properly, but afterwards simply call the wrong functions!)

---

In Java, each `import` affects only the file in which it is contained. This means that the above mentioned pollution can still occur locally in one file. (One could say: It's only the problem of the author who actually *caused* the namespace pollution, which is just fair)

Analogously to the case in the above mentioned link: Imagine you are using two libraries, "*foo*" and "*bar*". And out of laziness (or lack of knowledge of best practices), you are using the wildcard imports:

```
import foo.*:
import bar.*:

class MyClass {
    void someMethod() {

        // Assume that this class is from the "foo" librariy, and the
        // fully qualified name of this class is "foo.Example"
        Example e = new Example();
    }
}
```

Now imagine you upgrade your version of the "*bar*" library. And the new version contains a class called `bar.Example`. Then the above code will fail to compile, because the reference to the class `Example` is ambiguous.

The same problem can, by the way, also appear with [static imports](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html). It's a bit more delicate and subtle, and collisions are a bit more likely. That's why they say that you should use static imports *very sparingly*.

---

A side note: Of course, these collisions and ambiguities can easily be resolved. You can always use the fully qualified names instead. Most modern Java IDEs offer a functionality to organize/optimize the imports. For example, in Eclipse, you can always press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, which will (depending on the settings in *Preferences->Java->Code Style->Organize Imports*) replace *all* wildcard imports with the individual ones.

Comment: So, comparing to C++, pollution doesn't occur when the imports are done on a "global" scale (across all instances), like what Prashant pointed out?

Comment: That's right. The author of one file can not cause problems for others by polluting the namespace, because he will only affect his "own namespace" (that is, his own file).

Answer (score 4):

I think Java/C# have a different philosopyh than C++. Let me explain.

When you import something in Java you are only importing it in this part of the code. Let's say you have a class `A` in package `packageA`. Furthermore, `A` imports a class `B` in package `packageB` and `B` imports `java.util.LinkedList`. In C++, `A` would include a header-file to use `B` and in this header-file, you would have an `#include` for some `LinkedList`. So the `LinkedList` would be visible in `A`. In Java, this is not the case: class `A` must include `java.util.LinkedList` on its own to be able to use it. That said, you can still get namespace pollution, but they are more local (typically per-file). This is the reason, why you should avoid the asterisk when using `import`.

I cannot give a qualified answer for C# since I do not use it, but i think that their philosophy is similar.

Answer (score 1):

I think in Java and C# the imports are a short-hand, but the compiler recognizes each reference in the class with the fully-qualified name. So you write `new LinkedList<>()`, but the compiler understands that in this class at this time you mean `new java.util.LinkedList.LinkedList<>()`.

This solves the problem you were mentioning, I believe, since the full name of the class with the package absolutely must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Each **class loader** in your running ***Java*** program maintains its own **name-space**, which is populated by the names of all the **classes** it has loaded.

A `name-space` is a set of unique names for `loaded classes` that is maintained by the `Java Virtual Machine`. For example, once a `Java Virtual Machine` has loaded a class named `Volcano` into a particular `name-space`, it is impossible to load a different class named `Volcano` into that same `name-space`. You can load multiple `Volcano` classes into a `Java Virtual Machine`, however, because you can create `multiple name-spaces` inside a `Java application` by creating multiple `class loaders`. If you create three separate name-spaces (one for each of three class loaders) in a running `Java application`, then, by loading one `Volcano` class into each name-space, your program could load three different `Volcano` classes into your application.

If you are using same **class-loader** for all the *classes* in your application then all the `classes` will be loaded in  `same name space` only once. `Class Loader` will not load all these `classes` in subsequent access. also `classes` in one `name space` can not interact to classes in other `name space`.

Comment: I'm NOT the downvoter, but some people dislike it when many `technical` terms are randomly `backticked`. Although this does not affect the usefulness of the answer, someone might go so far and see it as a reason to downvote (but this is just a guess...)

Comment: From a purely technical point, maybe the relationship between a classloader, a package and a namespace is not described as clearly as someone would have expected it (but this also is just a guess..)