# Why using Macros in class for magic number readiblity is not right in class C++

Tags: c++, code-readability

I used Macros at top of class to tell what is 1 and 45.00 instead of just writing magic numbers.

Question is why using Macros in following class (see the default constructor) is not a good idea? Why using const int LIMIT_UNDER = 1 better? I think there is no difference.

But if I do use that constant at class data member level(global const is not a good thing we know), i.e.const int LIMIT_UNDER,
will I initialise it using constructor initializer list?

Class details:-

The Cube class which I have to calculate volume also. The class can have a user input of FLOAT length, width and height in between minimum 1 to maximum 45.00. Otherwise if user inputs any other numbers its all sides would be 1.

so it will be like

```
// Use MACRO or CONST???
#define LIMIT_UNDER 1
#define LIMIT_UPPER 45.00

class Cube {
  float height;
  float width;
  float length;

public:
  // Write setter getters here

  // default constructor
  Cube() {
    // default constructor puts default values
    height = width = length = LIMIT_UNDER;

  // Other code of class...
  )
```

Comment: If global const is a bad thing then macros are even worse. At least you could contain the constants in a namespace if you wanted to and they'd have a type.

Comment: @RetiredNinja How about declaring and initialize them as class data members and initiatlize them using constructor. It will be much of an effort though :( better to use your opinion of namespace then :)

Comment: When you trace your code in a debugger, it will not show the values of LIMIT_UNDER and LIMIT_UPPER.

Comment: @273K - You can actually get macros in your debugger with gcc/gdb if you crank the debug symbols high enough (`-ggdb3` works for sure, I haven't tested other flags)

Comment: @Stephen Please show me how to enable -ggdb3 in msvc. When I said "debugger", I didn't mean gdb.

Comment: Global constants are not a problem. Global *mutable* variables are the problem. The problem with globals is not the scope.

Comment: @273K - Note where I said "with gcc/gdb".  I agree with your sentiment regarding macros making it harder to debug, but it's a not a universal truth that the values won't show up in debuggers.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` constants in header files are generally considered bad because they [pollute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/267908/430766) all files that happen to include that header. Even worse, their value could be changed by other files via `#undef`.

Instead of using globally accessible symbols, try to keep things local to the scope in which they matter. For example:

```
class Cube {
  static constexpr float minLimit = 1.f;
  static constexpr float maxLimit = 45.f;

  float height = minLimit;
  float width = minLimit;
  float length = minLimit;
};
```

This will also implicitly create a constructor that initialises the members to the default value. No need to write a constructor manually.